# ParallelSubmit executes only on one kernel

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

I'm trying to use `Parallesubmit` to run some calculations in parallel, but it looks like all the calculations are evaluated at one kernel. Consider this example:

```
LaunchKernels[]
(* {"KernelObject"[1, "local"], "KernelObject"[2, "local"], 
 "KernelObject"[3, "local"], "KernelObject"[4, "local"]} *)

f[a_, b_, {min_, max_}] := Pause[1]

ls = {0, 1};

DistributeDefinitions[f]
(* {f} *)

evl = Table[ParallelSubmit[{n}, {f[1, 0, ls], $KernelID}], {n, 1, 8}]

WaitAll[evl] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {8.0152, {{Null, 4}, {Null, 3}, {Null, 2}, {Null, 1}, {Null, 
   4}, {Null, 3}, {Null, 2}, {Null, 1}}} *)
```

We can see that `$KernelID` reported that the work are distributed among four kernels, but the timing shows they are evaluated at one kernel.

For comparison, `ParallelTable` works as expected

```
ParallelTable[{f[1, 0, ls], $KernelID}, {n, 1, 
   8}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.00714, {{Null, 4}, {Null, 4}, {Null, 3}, {Null, 3}, {Null,
    2}, {Null, 2}, {Null, 1}, {Null, 1}}} *)
```

It appears that the problem may relate to the distribution of definition for `ls`, but why is there the inconsistency between `$KernelID` and `AbsoluteTiming`?

If `ParallelSubmit` doesn't know the definition of `ls`, I expect it to just complain, like in this example

```
t = 1;
evl = Table[ParallelSubmit[{n}, {Pause[t], $KernelID}], {n, 1, 4}];
WaitAll[evl]
```

> ```
> (kernel 4) Pause::numnm :  Non-negative machine-sized number expected at position 1 in Pause[t].
> (kernel 3) Pause::numnm :  Non-negative machine-sized number expected at position 1 in Pause[t].
> (kernel 2) Pause::numnm :  Non-negative machine-sized number expected at position 1 in Pause[t].
> (kernel 1) Pause::numnm :  Non-negative machine-sized number expected at position 1 in Pause[t].
> ```

```
(* {{Null, 4}, {Null, 3}, {Null, 2}, {Null, 1}} *)
```

Shall we consider this behavor as a bug?

Answer (score 5):

This is not a bug, and as you said the problem lies in the subkernels not knowing about `ls`. [Monitoring the communication](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31617/how-to-monitor-the-communication-between-parallel-kernels) between the main and subkernels with LinkSnooper you can see packets being exchanged like

> ```
> Master ---> Sub: EvaluatePacket[{Global`f[1, 0, Global`ls], $KernelID}]
> Master <--- Sub: ReturnPacket[{Global`f[1, 0, Global`ls], 1}]
> ```

While `$KernelID` does get evaluated in the subkernels, `f` just returns as is, since the third argument has to be a list with two elements, and the subkernel does not have a definition for `ls`. The ReturnPacket then gets processed in the main kernel, and as `ls` is now defined, `Pause[1]` is evaluated.

In your second example it is not `ParallelSubmit` or `WaitAll` that are complaining (how could they be aware that they should know about `ls`?), but `Pause` was not called with a numeric argument.

So there are three solutions:

1. Distribute the definition of `ls` to the subkernels

   ```
   DistributeDefinitions[ls];
   evl = Table[ParallelSubmit[{n}, {f[1, 0, ls], $KernelID}], {n, 1, 4}];
   WaitAll[evl] // AbsoluteTiming
   ```

> ```
> {2.04807, {{Null, 2}, {Null, 1}, {Null, 2}, {Null, 1}}}
> ```

2. Tell `ParallelSubmit` to substitute `ls` before sending everything off to the subkernels (as you did for `n`)

   ```
    evl = Table[ParallelSubmit[{n,ls}, {f[1, 0, ls], $KernelID}], {n, 1, 4}];
    WaitAll[evl] // AbsoluteTiming
   ```

> ```
> {2.02098, {{Null, 2}, {Null, 1}, {Null, 2}, {Null, 1}}}
> ```

3. Make `f` complain when not evaluated with proper arguments

   ```
   f::badArgs = "f called with impropper arguments";
   f[a_, b_, {min_, max_}] := Pause[1]
   f[___] := (Message[f::badArgs]; $Failed);

   DistributeDefinitions[f]

    evl = Table[ParallelSubmit[{n}, {f[1, 0, ls], $KernelID}], {n, 1, 4}];
    WaitAll[evl] // AbsoluteTiming
   ```

> ```
> f::badArgs :  f called with impropper arguments  
> f::badArgs :  f called with impropper arguments  
> f::badArgs :  f called with impropper arguments  
> f::badArgs :  f called with impropper arguments  
> {1.22837, {{$Failed, 4}, {$Failed, 3}, {$Failed, 2}, {$Failed, 1}}}
> ```